# asp.net masterpage - make hyperlink visible at runtime

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

Is it possible to alter the visible property of hyperlinks on a masterpage at runtime?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose the hyperlink as a property on the master page, you can get a reference to a pages master and cast that to your specific master page then set visibility of the hyperlinks using that property.

In your master page have something like this:

```
Public ReadOnly Property RemitViewerLink() As HyperLink
    Get
        Return hlRemitViewer
    End Get
End Property
```

Then in your child page you can do this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Dim MyMaster As MasterPage = DirectCast(Page.Master, MasterPage)
    MyMaster.RemitViewerLink.CssClass = "selectedMenuItem" 'or set visibility
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No, if you set visible=False then it won't even display in the HTML output of the page.  You would need to use javascript to hide/show the hyperlinks instead.